# pointer return value changes after function call

Tags: c, pointers, return-value

Code snippets from two C source files:

A.c

```
Channel *testChannelGet()
{
    Channel *ch = channelGet (parser,parserCh);
    return ch;
}
```

B.c

```
Channel *channelGet(UINT8 parser, UINT16 parserCh)
{
    chnl.player = &solPlayer;
    return((Channel *)&chnl);
}
```

I compile both files and create a static and a shared library. Now I call testChannelGet from a sample program. When I link it against the static library, it works perfectly. But if I link it against the shared library, its SEGFAULTing. Debugging tells me that the pointer returned from channelGet is changing the moment it returns. GDB output below.

```
174         Channel *ch = channelGet (parser,parserCh);
(gdb) s
channelGet (parser=1 '\001', parserCh=1) at B.c:15174
15174           chnl.player = &solPlayer;
(gdb) n
15175           return((Channel *)&chnl);
(gdb) p ((Channel *)&chnl)
$1 = (Channel *) 0x7ffff7fed1a0
(gdb) n
15176   }
(gdb) n
testChannelGet at A.c:175
175         return ch;
(gdb) p ch
$2 = (Channel *) 0xfffffffff7fed1a0
```

It seems the address value points to a different offset now - 0xfffffffff7fed1a0 vs 0x7ffff7fed1a0 . The last bytes in both addresses are the same.

Any hints? I have tried the -fPIC option to no avail.

Comment: What is `chnl` and where is it defined?

Comment: Its a global variable defined in B.c - Channel chnl; and initialized in another file, chnl = malloc(sizeof(Channel*));

Comment: It might be the case that when you call the dynamic lib the initialisation is not done?

Comment: i dont think initialization is the issue. I checked the contents of chnl inside the function and it looks good. And the static lib works with the same code. The address change is whats confusing me.

Comment: Your malloc is wrong - you are allocating the space for something the sizeof a pointer, you need to remove the asterisk to allocate space for the Channel. Because you've done this you haven't allocated enough space and get the SIGSEGV, you were just lucky it worked with the other library.

Comment: oops..that was a typo.. my malloc doesnt have the *. And I am able to inspect the contents of chnl before its returned and it looked good.

Comment: OK, is there another typo on that malloc line? malloc returns a pointer to a channel and you are assigning it to a 'channel'. Just a thought :)

Comment: Could you please tell us a few more details about your hardware, your OS, and your compiler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there a prototype in scope for `channelGet()` in `A.c`?

If not, the results you're seeing could be explained as follows:

- `channelGet()` is assumed to return `int` (due to lack of prototype), so the result is truncated to `0xf7fed1a0`
- then it is cast to a 64-bit pointer, so gets sign-extended to `0xfffffffff7fed1a0`

(You should get complaints about this if you compile with warnings enabled, of course...)

Comment: I do have the prototype in a header file, which is included in both A.c and B.c. And would it work for the static libraries if the problem was lack of prototype?

Comment: BTW when I use the static library, the addresses are always in the 32 bit range. Do I need any compiler flag when I create the shared lib? I am using - gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname

Comment: You note that the addresses are all in the 32-bit range in the static case: Linux x86_64 binaries are usually linked to run at a low address, 0x400000, and if all the addresses in question are < 0x80000000, a truncation followed by a sign extension will have no effect. But dynamic libraries are loaded at much higher addresses.  So, yes, it's quite conceivable that it could work for a static library without the prototype, but not a dynamic library.  As for compiler flags, I can't think of anything obvious, but without seeing how you're compiling and linking each component, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: hey, that was the problem! my header file wasn't included because of some funny #ifdef. I did a gcc -E, and read the preprocessor output, and the prototype wasn't there. Fixed it and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot, Matthew!!

Answer (score 1):

Run your program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).  Find and fix any errors it reports.

Comment: it runs perfectly in valgrind! thats vexing me too :(

Comment: Then try to distill your problem down to a complete but minimal example and we'll have a crack at it.  Don't forget to include the build process you're using, which could be the culprit.